# Only one item can be added at a time to cart

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

I can only add one item to my cart at a time.
The previous item I add to the cart will just get replaced here is my method I use:

```
public function addcart(){

    if(isset($this->session->userdata)){
        $type = $this->session->userdata('type');
        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

         $this->db->select('id_product ,price');
         $query = $this->db->get('product', array('title'=> $this->input->post('title')));

     $cart['product'] = $this->cart->contents();
         if($query->num_rows() >0){

            $row = $query->row();
             $id = $row->id_product;

            $cart['product'][$id] = array(

            'id'     => $row->id_product,
           'qty'     => $this->input->post('quantity'),
           'price'   => $row->price,
           'name'    => $this->input->post('title'),
           //'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')

        );

        $this->cart->insert($cart['product'][$id]);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show `$this->cart->insert()` method?

Answer (score 0):

check what $cart['product'] = $this->cart->contents(); returns to you
if there is a problem there it probably reset your array of products and then you insert the second product and get a total cart of one product

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `$this->db->get()` badly, you are searching product by string, which is not "correct". What happens if you have same (title) identical products? You get the first one/second one?

please adjust your table as follows

`id, title, price... 'custom fields', active`

make `id` as autoincrement, `active` as boolean (so you can later turn on/off product)

Make your method accept parameters:

```
public function addcart( $id = FALSE ) {

  if ($id === FALSE || !is_numeric($id)) {
    //wrong ID do nothing or throw alert or inform user about it
    redirect('');

  }

  if(isset($this->session->userdata)) {

    $type     = $this->session->userdata('type');
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $this->db->select('id_product ,price');
    $query = $this->db->get('product', array('id' => $id, 'active' => '1'));

    $cart['product'] = $this->cart->contents();

    if($query->num_rows() >0) {

      $row  = $query->row();
      $id   = $row->id_product;

      $cart['product'][$id] = array(
          'id'     => $row->id_product,
          'qty'     => $this->input->post('quantity'),
          'price'   => $row->price,
          'name'    => $this->input->post('title'),
          //'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
      );

      $this->cart->insert($cart['product'][$id]);

    }

  }

}
```

Happy cod(e)igniting.